# htaccess rules - multi-language website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, multilingual

I created a language script in my website. This script recognizes the language in the URL and loads the language definitions.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/about/?$ sobre2.php?lang=$1    <-- working fine
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/?$ contato2.php?lang=$1  <-- working fine
RewriteRule ^(.+)/products/?$ produtos2.php?lang=$1  <-- working fine
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/sales/?$ contato-vendas2.php?lang=$1  <-- working fine
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/general/?$ contato-form2.php?lang=$1  <-- working fine
```

The pages above are accessed, respectively, as this:

```
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/about/
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/contact/
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/products/
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/contact/sales/
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/contact/general/
```

This is working fine in all pages, except index.

When I try to do the same thing with the index page, using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index2.php?lang=$1
```

Besides it doesn't work, it also affects all the other pages (and resources), so the resources are not loaded and the page looks like a "pure html".

I'd like to know how can I configure the htaccess to make my "index2.php" be accessible like this:

```
https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.+` will match 1 or more of any character and if you place rule before other rules then this will make other rules ineffective.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /b2b/

RewriteRule ^((?!pt-br/).*)$ pt-br/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/about/?$ sobre2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/?$ contato2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/products/?$ produtos2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/sales/?$ contato-vendas2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/contact/general/?$ contato-form2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})/?$ index2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you very much, it's working perfectly. Is it possible to detect if someome access the site without the language code and then redirect them? For exemple: if the user access the link "https://domain.com/b2b", he's redirected to "https://domain.com/b2b/pt-br".

Comment: Well, it worked perfectly, but only in "index". What can I do to make it work in *any* page? For exemple: if the user access "domain.com/b2b/contact" he'll be redirected to  "domain.com/b2b/pt-br/contact". I'm sorry for didn't explain it better.

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting error 404 even when I enter with "/pt-br/"

Comment: What is the exact URL you entered? You should enter `http://domain.com/b2b/pt-br/`